# "error: package DownloadTask does not exist " FileDownloader library

Tags: android, download

I'm trying to use okdownload library it's new version for `FileDownloader library`  ... I'm new in android and i didn't find any tutorial to using `FileDownloader library` ...

**my code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/storynory-1e523.appspot.com/o/audio%2Ffear-interview-jana-andrew-west.mp3?alt=media&token=1a279250-baa4-490a-b165-a6b2ff718763";
        String fileName   = "my Photo2.mp3";

        String dirPath    = com.example.abdullah.myapplication.Utils.getRootDirPath(getApplicationContext());

        task = new DownloadTask.Builder(url, dirPath)
                .setFilename("my Photo2.mp3")
                // the minimal interval millisecond for callback progress
                .setMinIntervalMillisCallbackProcess(30)
                // do re-download even if the task has already been completed in the past.
                .setPassIfAlreadyCompleted(false)
                .build();

        task.enqueue(listener);

        // cancel
        task.cancel();

        // execute task synchronized
        task.execute(listener);

    }

}
```

i imported `implementation "com.liulishuo.okdownload:okhttp:1.0.3"` into my gradle file

i don't know how to use this library ...may someone correct my code please!

Answer (score 0):

I never used this library but on one site they added some core "okdownload" as well:

implementation "com.liulishuo.okdownload:okdownload:1.0.3"